# Accessing FAcebook contacts

Tags: php

Are there any tutorials or example code for reading Facebook friends list (using Facebook API) with PHP?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Facebook-Programming-API-Friends-P851.html